# How To Make This JFrame Code More Simple?

Tags: java, swing

I have just started learning JFrame, and I tried to make a simple calculator. It works, but it's also repetitive, having to make an ActionListener for each button. Is there a way to make it more simple?

```
public class gui extends JFrame
{
    private JButton one;
    private JButton two;
    private JButton three;
    private JButton four;
    private JButton five;
    private JButton six;
    private JButton seven;
    private JButton eight;
    private JButton nine;
    public double first  = 0;
    public double second = 0;
    public double sum    = 0;

    public gui() 
    {   
        super("title");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        one   = new JButton("1"); //makes a new button to click.
        two   = new JButton("2");
        three = new JButton("3");
        four  = new JButton("4");
        five  = new JButton("5");
        six   = new JButton("6");
        seven = new JButton("7");
        eight = new JButton("8");
        nine  = new JButton("9");
        one.addActionListener( //MAKES NEW INNER CLASS TO DEFINE WHAT ONE DOES
            new ActionListener() 
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
                { 
                    // checks if clicked. 
                    if (first == 0) first = 1;
                    else second = 1;

                    if (first != 0 && second != 0) 
                    {
                        sum = first + second;
                        System.out.println(sum);
                        first = 0;
                        second = 0;
                    }
                }
            });
        two.addActionListener( 

                new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { 
                        if(first == 0) {
                        first = 2;
                        }else {
                            second = 2;
                        }
                        if(first != 0 && second != 0) {
                            sum = first + second;
                            System.out.println(sum);
                            first = 0;
                            second = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        three.addActionListener( 

                new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { 
                        if(first == 0) {
                        first = 3;
                        }else {
                            second = 3;
                        }
                        if(first != 0 && second != 0) {
                            sum = first + second;
                            System.out.println(sum);
                            first = 0;
                            second = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        four.addActionListener(

                new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                        if(first == 0) {
                        first = 4;
                        }else {
                            second = 4;
                        }
                        if(first != 0 && second != 0) {
                            sum = first + second;
                            System.out.println(sum);
                            first = 0;
                            second = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        five.addActionListener(

                new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { 
                        if(first == 0) {
                        first = 5;
                        }else {
                            second = 5;
                        }
                        if(first != 0 && second != 0) {
                            sum = first + second;
                            System.out.println(sum);
                            first = 0;
                            second = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        six.addActionListener( 

                new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { 
                        if(first == 0) {
                        first = 6;
                        }else {
                            second = 6;
                        }
                        if(first != 0 && second != 0) {
                            sum = first + second;
                            System.out.println(sum);
                            first = 0;
                            second = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        seven.addActionListener(

                new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { 
                        if(first == 0) {
                        first = 7;
                        }else {
                            second = 7;
                        }
                        if(first != 0 && second != 0) {
                            sum = first + second;
                            System.out.println(sum);
                            first = 0;
                            second = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        eight.addActionListener(

                new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { 
                        if(first == 0) {
                        first = 8;
                        }else {
                            second = 8;
                        }
                        if(first != 0 && second != 0) {
                            sum = first + second;
                            System.out.println(sum);
                            first = 0;
                            second = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        nine.addActionListener( 

                new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { 
                        if(first == 0) {
                        first = 9;
                        }else {
                            second = 9;
                        }
                        if(first != 0 && second != 0) {
                            sum = first + second;
                            System.out.println(sum);
                            first = 0;
                            second = 0;

                        }
                    }
                }
            );

        add(one);
        add(two);
        add(three);
        add(four);
        add(five);
        add(six);
        add(seven);
        add(eight);
        add(nine);

    }

}
```

Also I can't find a way to "combine" two numbers that I have. If the user presses 9 and 2, I want to combine those two numbers to make 92. How would I do that?

Comment: One obvious possibility would be to make an ActionListener class (rather than than an anonymous class) that takes a parameter (like in a constructor) that tells it the number to use, rather than hard-coding the number in each separate class like you have now.  However, I think your question is off-top for SO.  It might be better on the Code Review site. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You *really* should be using an array right now. The code would be roughly 9x shorter and *much* easier to expand. What would you do if you needed 500 `JButton`s? And then you realize that you wanted to tweak one tiny thing? You'd have to make that change in 500 places. Arrays fix that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do to remove a lot of repetition is to use a single `ActionListener` for all your buttons.  You can set an `actionCommand` attribute on each button that the action listener will use to detect which button was pressed.

Here's a general illustration:

```
private ActionListener btnListener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getActionCommand()) {
            case "0": 
            case "1": 
               // ...
            case "9":
                enterDigit(event.getActionCommand());
                break;                    
        }
    }
};

public gui(){
    one = new JButton("1");
    one.setActionCommand("1");
    one.addActionListener(btnListener);
    two = new JButton("2");
    two.setActionCommand("2");
    two.addActionListener(btnListener);
    // ...
}
```

As for how to combine separate number button presses to form larger numbers, there could be several ways, depending on how you want to store your numbers.
It might be easiest to start out using `String`s, in which case you just append a `String` containing the input digit (which came from the actionCommand of the `JButton`) onto the existing `String` of previously entered digits:

```
private String numberInDisplay = "";

// remember enterDigit from the ActionListener above?  This is it...
private void enterDigit(String digit){
    numberInDisplay = numberInDisplay + digit;
}
```

If you want to use a numeric type, such as a `long`, you simply multiply the existing number by ten and add the value of the new digit:

```
private long numberInDisplay = 0;
private void enterDigit(String digit){ 
    numberInDisplay = numberInDisplay * 10 + Long.valueOf(digit);
```

Of course this is a rather simplified example.  There will be some additional complications if you want to handle decimal points, negative signs, scientific notation, etc., but it should at least get you started down the right path.